# Axios.delete() No funciona? laravel+vue 2.0 + axios

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

Recien empiezo con vue y laravel y me encuentro con este problema que no logro resolver:
Quiero eliminar un registro de la base de datos usando axios. Intento con el siguiente código:

```
 taskDelete(id){
            axios.delete(`/notas/${id}`).then(res=>{

            }).catch(e =>{
                console.log(e.response)
            })
            
        }
```

ruta:

```
Route::resource('notas', 'NotaController')->middleware('auth');
```

Controlador:

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $nota = Nota::find($id);
        $nota->delete();
    }
```

Pero recibo este error: `app.js:285 DELETE http://localhost/notas/1 405 (Method Not Allowed)`

Cabe aclarar que el parámetro de la función `taskDelete` es el id que recojo de la tarea existente que se visualiza en la web por medio de un botón con el evento `@click`. Si ejecuto un console.log obtengo el id pero no se realiza el delete.
-instalé las dependencias para usar axios.

Que estoy haciendo mal? agradezco la ayuda

Comment: Podrías correr el comando `php artisan route:list` y mostrar el resultado en la pregunta?

Comment: Lo he solucionado agregando ``Request $request`` a la función destroy y en lugar de traer el id específico directamente, saco el item y su index quedando así la función vue: ``taskDelete(item,index){axios.delete(`notas/${item.id}`)``

Comment: Vale, agrega eso que comentas como respuesta, así le puede servir a futuros lectores con el mismo problema.